# Tracking App Installs on iOS 14 from Facebook Ads for Child-Focused Apps without Ad ID: Best Practices

Tags: ios, app-store, facebook-events, facebook-ads, skadnetwork

We have added the Facebook SDK to our child-focused app and are receiving install events on the Events Manager. However, we are facing a challenge in tracking app installs on iOS 14 devices and attributing them to a Facebook Ads campaign. This is because we cannot enable and send the Ad ID to Facebook due to the nature of our app.

The Facebook Ads Manager page reports that "These conversions are reported to Meta from Apple's SKAdNetwork API. Statistical modeling may be used to account for some conversions." While this provides some level of insight, we need to obtain the precise number of installs to effectively measure the success of our Facebook Ads campaign.

Given these constraints, what is the most effective method to track conversions from our Facebook Ads campaign? We want to ensure that we can accurately attribute installs to our campaign and make data-driven decisions to optimize our advertising efforts.